# How to force sign out user using Firebase Auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign out of the application using the Firebase Auth built with firebase. This actually logs the user out, but it doesn't work render the new page and gives me:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
 // sign out
    const signOut = (history ) => {
      doSignOut().then(() => {props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN)})
    }
    // 
    firestore.collection('customers').doc(userID).collection('subscriptions')
      .where('status', '==', 'trialing' || "active").get()
      .then(activeSubscriptions => {
        // if this is true, the user has no active subscription.
        if (activeSubscriptions.empty === false) {
          console.log("line 31")
          {signOut(props.history)}
        }
      });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work about `firebase.auth.signOut()`? As in: what unexpected behavior do you see after that line executes?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've actually edited my question with an updated error

Comment: So it looks like `props.history` is undefined. Did you mean for that to be `history.push(...)` instead of `props.history.push(...)`?

Comment: what I did was actually imported created a function `const signOut = (history ) => {
  doSignOut().then(() => {props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN)})
}` , and then called this function from where I needed to, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Good to hear @Gianluca. You might want to post that as a self-answer to provide closure to this post, and so other can more easily benefit from your learnings in the future.